# Can't figure out the correct type for a HashMap

Tags: java

```
filter.put("a", EnumA.class);I got following setup:

public interface InterfaceA {
  abstract public Object[] foo();
}

public enum EnumA implements InterfaceA {
  RED();
  ...
}

public enum EnumB implements InterfaceA {
  OAK();
  ...
}
```

now i want to use this construct typesave, i got this:

```
private <T extends Enum<T> & InterfaceA> void  importSettingViaEnum(Class<T> clazz) { ...
    for (T elem : clazz.getEnumConstants()){
        ... = f(elem.ordinal());
        ... = elem.foo();
        ...
    }
}
```

this seems to be correct, the clazz should only work work the enums above. But now, i can't figure out the correct type of this map, this is not working:

```
public <T extends Enum<T> & InterfaceA> Main() {
    Map<String, Class<T>> filter = new HashMap<>();
    filter.put("a", EnumA.class);
    filter.put("b", EnumB.class);
    importSettingViaEnum(filter.get("a"));
}
```

Someone has a clue ? I wish to have this thing typesafe.

Here some pastebin: https://pastebin.com/fKxtBGBe

---

**EDIT 1:**

Tried something like this, but it won't work...

```
public Main() {
        Map<String, Class<? extends Enum<? extends InterfaceA>>> filter = new HashMap<>();
        filter.put("a", EnumA.class);
        filter.put("b", EnumB.class);
        importSettingViaEnum(filter.get("a")); // BREAK THE BUILD
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Type erasure... provide the type object of the generic type parameter.

```
public <T extends Enum<T> & InterfaceA> void main(Class<T> type) {
    Map<String, Class<T>> filter = new HashMap<>();
    filter.put("a", type);
    //importSettingViaEnum(filter.get("a"));
}

    main(EnumA.class);
```

This also decouples the implementation type (EnumA).

---

Or go for partial type safeness

```
public void main2() {
    Map<String, Class<? extends InterfaceA>> filter = new HashMap<>();
    filter.put("a", EnumA.class);
    Class<? extends InterfaceA> type = filter.get("a");
    if (type.isEnum()) {
        ....
    }
}
```

Cast type to Enum if needed.

Comment: *provide the type object of the generic type parameter.* +1 for that bit

Comment: Is this somehow solving my problem? in my eyes it's just shifting the problem one level higher. What if i have "filter.put("b", EnumB.class);" additionaly? i have to call main(Class clazz) for each enum.

Comment: @DennisOchocki you are right concerning the shifting, so opt for a partial type safeness, extended the answer.

Comment: @DennisOchocki At some level you need to define the type anyway.

Comment: @nullpointer isn't it enough to say it is a class, wich is a enum which implements InterfaceA? If i can write Class, why can't i specify it with my restrictions [Class<? ...>]?

Comment: @JoopEggen but still i would have a typecast, even if i know, it will work, typecasting is a thing i don't like.

Comment: _Generic_ code should go with the `Enum` base class, not `EnumA`. I found it weird, that the generic method Main accessed EnumA. I would go by adding EnumA functionality as API in InterfaceA. _My guess: it is still too early to go for nice architecture,_ Avoid having many cases for EnumA, EnumB and so on. And program it out first.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to create a map of a sting to a class, this should work for you :

```
Map<String, Class> filter = new HashMap<>(); // any Class put against a string in the map
filter.put("a", EnumA.class);
```

Comment: " I wish to have this thing typesafe." You can add any class with this code.